# push sqlite database file into phone

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sdcard

I need to push sqlite database file to phone app storage location.
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834241/how-to-use-adb-command-to-push-a-file-on-device-without-sd-card) for my app package database.But not working.Is there any way?

I have tried using below command in device shell, but getting device not found message.

```
shell@android: adb push MY_DB_FILE /data/data/MY_PACKAGE_NAME/databases/
```

Comment: that u want to copy database from Assest to sdcard

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar are asking me or telling me the way.Please elaborate.

Comment: You can't write to `/data/data/` unless your phone is rooted and you have `su`, or your app is writing the database file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Call the write() method shown below whenever you want your database file. It will create a backupname.db file in the root folder of your device.(you can change the name of the .db file in the backupDBPath string)

```
private void write() throws IOException {
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    if (sd.canWrite()) {

        String currentDBPath = DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME;
        String backupDBPath = "backupname.db";
        File currentDB = new File(getDBPath(), currentDBPath);
        File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

        if (currentDB.exists()) {
            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());

            src.close();
            dst.close();

        }
    }
}

private String getDBPath() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        return getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath().replace("files", "databases") + File.separator;
    } else {
        return getFilesDir().getPath() + getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    }
}
```

Comment: whoever has downvoted, can you plz tell what's wrong with this, as its working all fine in my project.